# RabbitMQ Docker Container Error: Error when reading /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie: eacces

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am having a problem with running `rabbitmq` from within Docker on Windows Server 1709 (Windows Server core edition).

I am using docker-compose to create the rabbitmq service. If I run the docker-compose on my local computer, everything works fine. When I run the docker-compose on the windows server (where docker has been set to docker lcow support on windows) I get the above mentioned error multiple times occurring the in the logs. Namely this error is:

> Error when reading /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie: eacces

It is worth noting that I receive this error even if I just do a manual pull of rabbitmq and a manual run with  `docker run -itd --rm --name rabbitmq rabbitmq:3-management`

I am able to bash into the container for a short while before it crashes and exits and I see the following:

```
root@localhost:~# ls -la
---------- 2 root root   20 Jan  5 12:18 .erlang.cookie
```

On my localhost, the permissions look like this (which is correct):

```
root@localhost:~# ls -la 
-r-------- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq   20 Dec 28 00:00 .erlang.cookie
```

I can't understand why the permission structure is broken on the server.

Is it possible that this is an issue with LCOW support on Windows Server 1709 with Docker for Windows? Or is the problem with rabbitmq?

For reference here is the docker compose file used:

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: localhost
    ports: 
      - "1001:5672"
      - "1002:15672"
    environment:
      - "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user"
      - "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password"
    volumes:
      - d:/docker_data/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
    restart: always
```

For reference here is the docker information where there error is happening.

`docker info`

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 17.10.0-ee-preview-3
Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
 LCOW:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: process
Kernel Version: 10.0 16299 (16299.15.amd64fre.rs3_release.170928-1534)
Operating System: Windows Server Datacenter
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.905GiB
Name: ServerName
Docker Root Dir: D:\docker-root
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

`docker version`

```
Client:
 Version:      17.10.0-ee-preview-3
 API version:  1.33
 Go version:   go1.8.4
 Git commit:   1649af8
 Built:        Fri Oct  6 17:52:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.10.0-ee-preview-3
 API version:  1.34 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.4
 Git commit:   b8571fd
 Built:        Fri Oct  6 18:01:48 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Comment: It looks like mounting host dir on windows in not the same like mounting on windows. Can you provide compose file you used on linux? Take careful look on mounting. It's bot rabbit problem here

Comment: We do not have a linux machine, and therefore no linux compose file. The change on the mounting for linux would look like this though `/docker_data/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia`. The concern that I have is that local windows 10 works perfectly. When doing this on a Windows Server 2016 (1709 update) it does not work.

Comment: Any luck with this issue? Other questions seem recommending using CHMOD 600 on the cookie file maybe in your Dockerfile as a RUN cmd

Comment: Sadly we never did come right with this issue. If I remember, we did try do a chmod 600, but I think that once the container ran, it reverted back to 400. It may be an issue specifically with Windows Server 2016 (1709 update). Unfortunately, this project has come to an end, and I don't have access to the Windows Server version anymore, so I can't try to replicate it again :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with same problem when run RabbitMQ inside AWS ECS container

Disclaimer: I didn't check this behavior in detail and that is only my assumption, so **the problem cause may be wrong**, but at least solution is working

It feels like RabbitMQ creating `.erlang.cookie` file on container start if it doesn't exist. And if inside-container user is `root`:

```yaml
...
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    # set container user to root
    user: 0:0
...
```

then `.erlang.cookie` will be created with `root` permissions. But RabbitMQ starting child processes with `rabbitmq` user permissions. And `.erlang.cookie` is not writeable (editable) in this case.

To avoid this problem, I created custom image with existing `.erlang.cookie` file using `Dockerfile`:

```bash
ARG COOKIE_VALUE=SomeDefaultRandomString01
FROM rabbitmq:3.11-alpine

ARG COOKIE_VALUE=$COOKIE_VALUE

RUN printf 'log.console = true\nlog.console.level = warning\nlog.default.level = warning\nlog.connection.level = warning\nlog.channel.level = warning\nlog.file.level = warning\n' > /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-logs_to_stdout.conf && \
    printf 'loopback_users.guest = false\n' > /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/20-allow_remote_guest_users.conf && \
    printf 'management_agent.disable_metrics_collector = true' > /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/30-disable_metrics_data.conf && \
    chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/* && mkdir -p /var/lib/rabbitmq/ && \
    echo "$COOKIE_VALUE" > /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie && chmod 400 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie && \
    chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq
```

where `.erlang.cookie` value may be any random string, but it should be same for all nodes in RabbitMQ cluster (extra information [here](http://www.freekb.net/Article?id=3452#:%7E:text=The%20Erlang%20cookie%20is%20a,is%20stored%20in%20a%20file.)).

Comment: So, I'm not longer running this project anymore; but what you've described sounds like it makes sense. I think that might actually be what was happening. With that said, I do want to just check - have you confirmed that this works 100%? I can't confirm it because I don't have that source code anymore that I used when creating the question. I only ask because you say you haven't checked it in detail, but if the solution works, then definitely worth marking as accepted to help others down the line :) just need confirmation please

Comment: I didn't check cause of the problem and it may be different for our cases. Also in my case after multiple restarts container is properly starting even if I didn't apply the solution, what is little bit strange. Looks like here is a race condition and sometimes Rabbit creates `.erlang.cookie` in time. So probably here's some more effective solution. But I can guarantee that 1. I had same error in logs, 2. After creation cookie file by `RUN` command the problem is gone. By the way, only three last lines of  `RUN` is a problem solution. I just copied `Dockerfile` as is from my environment.